# How to add item in combobox in worksheet VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I need to add the item in combobox that is available on worksheet no in userform. The data is dynamic based on the specified range. This is my code and it does not work. There are multiple of standard, e.g. standard1, standard2 until standardiLast.

```
Private Sub AvailStd_DropButtonClick()

Dim choicesheet As Object, iLast As Integer, iCount As Integer

Set choicesheet = Worksheets("Test")

iLast = choicesheet.Range("LastLine").Cells(1, 1)


For iCount = 1 To iLast
With choicesheet.OLEObjects("AvailStd").Object

    .AddItem_

     iCount& "." & choicesheet.Range("Standard" & iCount).Cells(1, 1)

End With
Next iCount




End Sub
```

Comment: Please, post your code as text!

Comment: what is range("Standard" & iCount)?

Comment: this is not a code, but a screen-shot of your code, please upload your code (as copible text)

Comment: @ShaiRado edited, sorry, im new here

Comment: You can just Record Macro of adding item to the list and check the generated code

Comment: @dgorti range("Standard" & iCount) is the named range in my sheet. There are multiple table in my sheet which named as Standard1, Standard2...

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Private Sub AvailStd_DropButtonClick()
    Static filled As Boolean '<--| static variable to last between events

    Dim iLast As Long, iCount As Long
    Dim cb As ComboBox

    If filled Then '<--| if combobox already filled up then exit and let the user selection be taken into account
        filled = False '<--| next time fill the combobox up
        Exit Sub
    Else '<--| otherwise fill the combobox up
        With Worksheets("Test")
            iLast = .Range("LastLine").Cells(1, 1)
            Set cb = .OLEObjects("AvailStd").Object
            cb.Clear
            For iCount = 1 To iLast
                cb.AddItem .Range("Standard" & iCount).Cells(1, 1)
            Next
            filled = True '<--| mark combobox is already filled up
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: It works fine, but I cannot select the item in the combo box.

Comment: @mfo_28, did you get through it?